# Android does not show dialog in OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am calling the camera intent and handle the bitmap in the onActivityResult(). I am processing the image via NDK which is working fine. Then I want to open a dialog to present the image, but nothing happens.

```
   private void startIrisRoutine(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    File tempDir = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + Constants.DIR_TEMP);
    tempDir.mkdirs();

    // create file for taken photo
    final File inputFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_INPUT + Constants.END_JPG);

    // create face part files in temp folder
    final File facePartFace = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_FACE + Constants.END_PNG);
    final File facePartEyeRight = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_EYE_RIGHT + Constants.END_PNG);
    final File facePartEyeLeft = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_EYE_LEFT + Constants.END_PNG);

    //create texture files
    final File textureWahetRightFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_TEXTURE + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_RIGHT + Constants.END_PNG);
    final File textureCahtRightFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_TEXTURE + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_RIGHT + Constants.END_PNG);
    final File textureWahetLeftFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_TEXTURE + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_LEFT + Constants.END_PNG);
    final File textureCahtLeftFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_TEXTURE + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_LEFT + Constants.END_PNG);

    // create temp segmentation files
    final File segmentationWahetRightFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_SEGMENTS + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_RIGHT + Constants.END_JPG);
    final File segmentationCahtRightFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_SEGMENTS + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_RIGHT + Constants.END_JPG);
    final File segmentationWahetLeftFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_SEGMENTS + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_LEFT + Constants.END_JPG);
    final File segmentationCahtLeftFile = new File(tempDir + File.separator + Constants.FILE_SEGMENTS + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.FILE_EYE_LEFT + Constants.END_JPG);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mUSITHelper.findFaceParts(inputFile, facePartFace, facePartEyeLeft, facePartEyeRight);

    mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(facePartEyeLeft, textureWahetLeftFile, segmentationWahetLeftFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET);
    mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(facePartEyeLeft, textureCahtLeftFile, segmentationCahtLeftFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT);
    mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(facePartEyeRight, textureWahetRightFile, segmentationWahetRightFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET);
    mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(facePartEyeRight, textureCahtRightFile, segmentationCahtRightFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertadd.setCancelable(false);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_segmen, null);

    alertadd.setTitle("Only select properly segmented pictures:");

    alertadd.setView(view);
    alertadd.setNegativeButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
    alertadd.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            dlg.dismiss();
        }
    });
    final Dialog dialog = alertadd.create();
    dialog.show();

    ImageView ivWahetLeft = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivWahetLeft);
    ivWahetLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createIrisTemplate(textureWahetLeftFile, segmentationWahetLeftFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT, Constants.EYE_POSITION_LEFT);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    final ImageView ivCahtLeft = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivCahtLeft);
    ivCahtLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createIrisTemplate(textureCahtLeftFile, segmentationCahtLeftFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT, Constants.EYE_POSITION_LEFT);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    ImageView ivWahetRight = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivWahetRight);
    ivWahetRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createIrisTemplate(textureWahetRightFile, segmentationWahetRightFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT, Constants.EYE_POSITION_RIGHT);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    ImageView ivCahtRight = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivCahtRight);
    ivCahtRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createIrisTemplate(textureCahtRightFile, segmentationCahtRightFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT, Constants.EYE_POSITION_RIGHT);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + segmentationWahetLeftFile, ivWahetLeft);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + segmentationCahtLeftFile, ivCahtLeft);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + segmentationCahtRightFile, ivCahtRight);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + segmentationWahetRightFile, ivWahetRight);
}
```

Now i figured out that on other machines (not on mine) there is an error thrown:

```
MainActivity has leaked window that was originally added here
```

I have the feeling that code from the onCreate() method is sometimes canceling the dialog? Although only UI stuff and some backend communication is started

**UPDATE**: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x24 in tid 12737 (RenderThread) when running the app on another deivce (faster, SGS6 instead of SGS$). Dialog shows up and I get this error when clicking one of the imageviews

Comment: Where *exactly* you call this code? I assume that you're not processing your image on the main thread

Comment: I call it in the onActivityresult(), not starting a new Thread on my own. Not sure how NDK stuff is handled. Anyways the NDK part is still working fine (I get all the logs and files are created). But then the dialog just won't show up. I Also add ImageViews to the dialog to show processed images. When I call callOnClick() I get a Fatal error (seems like some memory is accesses, which is not allowed)

Comment: Can you verify that `dialog.show()` is actually reached?

Comment: Yes. Also it seems to be quite random when the dialog is not shown. Sometimes it is properly opened, sometimes not. I couldn't see any pattern yet

Comment: I just edited the question, and added the full method which is directly called in onActivityResult()

Comment: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's. Could this be the cause of the error? I tried other approaches like using getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), but I still got the same error

Comment: try to wrap the function into the runOnUiThread() ; method

Comment: @aelimill I did it already with the same result

Comment: If you remove the dialog.show() does it crash? Can you post the full stack trace from logcat? Also, are you using a native thread to render the image?

Comment: Is it a  memory problem?If you don't leave MainActivity,will it go wrong?You should remember to dismiss on OnDestroy forever.

Comment: Try setting a flag in `OnActivityResult` that you need to display the dialog, and check for that flag in `onResume`, then create your dialog there instead of in `OnActivityResult`.

Comment: @4ndro1d, which device you are using ?

Comment: @AlexTownsend answer it to get the bounty

Comment: @4ndro1d answer added. Didn't realize that fixed it for you, happy to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting a flag in `OnActivityResult` that you need to display the dialog, and check for that flag in `onResume`, then create your dialog there instead of in `OnActivityResult`.

More information on why it is a bad idea to commit a fragment transaction (in this case show a dialog) in activity lifecycle method can be found [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you make to appear your dialog in MainActivity, you may check a flag that your MainActivity is on foreground.

It can be possible like this:

```
boolean isActivityResumed = true;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // When activity is in focus, it will be on resumed.
    super.onResume();
    isActivityResumed = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // When activity is out of focus, it will be on paused.
    super.onPause();
    isActivityResumed = false;
}
```

Then, check this flag when you show your dialog:

```
if (isActivityResumed && dialog != null) {
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your dialog like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Only select properly segmented pictures:");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_segmen);
    Button dialogButtonRetry= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonRetry);
    dialogButtonRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
    Button dialogButtonDone= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonDone);
    dialogButtonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

To get your ivWahetLeft

```
ImageView ivWahetLeft = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivWahetLeft);
```